# needs to find how many times each number in a column appears and adding a column to show the count

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need help with microsoft sql query,

here is my result generated from my current query (huge query),

```
mrn   name   Med1  Med2  Med4
123   A      abd   abd    bcd
234   B      bdd   ddf    ggg
123   A      fff   rrr    ggg
234   B      ppp   kkk    jjj
345   C      jjj   kkk    jjj
456   D      adf   ghj    ffg
```

I am expecting

```
mrn   name  count  Med1  Med2  Med4
123   A      2     abd   abd    bcd
234   B      2     bdd   ddf    ggg
123   A      2     fff   rrr    ggg
234   B      2     ppp   kkk    jjj
345   C      1     jjj   kkk    jjj
456   D      1     adf   ghj    ffg
```

...

...

I tried `select *, count(mrn),` but it gave me an error saying mrn is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Comment: You want a *windowed* `COUNT`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify all your columns in 'group by' clause.

```
select mrn, name, count(*) 
from
<your very huge query>
group by mrn, name
```

But if you need to get all of your rows, you can use count as a window function:

```
select *, count(*) over (partition by mrn,name) from ...
```